# Multi table SQL query returning unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have a table called 'ELEMENTS.'  In this query, there should be as many results as there are rows in ELEMENTS.

The ELEMENT table has numeric values that correspond to text values in other tables.  I have drawn this picture that has the relationships.  The lines indicate the corresponding keys and the circles are the text values that I need.

[image]

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  ELEMENTS.RID,
        TAXONOMIES.SHORT_DESCRIPTION,
        type,
        ELEMENT_NAME,
        ELEMENT_ID,
        SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS.DESCRIPTION,
        namespace_prefix,
        datatype_localname 
FROM ELEMENTS,SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS,TAXONOMIES,SCHEMAS,DATA_TYPES  
WHERE
    ELEMENTS.TAXONOMY_ID = TAXONOMIES.RID AND
    ELEMENTS.SUBSTITUTION_GROUP_ID = SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS.RID AND 
    ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_SCHEMA_ID = SCHEMAS.RID AND
    ELEMENTS.DATA_TYPE_ID = DATA_TYPES.RID
```

this gives me 20 or so records when I should have thousands.  I've looked at the records but can't figure out a pattern in the records it IS showing.

Comment: +1 well-structured and specific question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you dimensions are either NULL or incompletely populated.  You can fix this by using `left outer join`:

```
SELECT ELEMENTS.RID, TAXONOMIES.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, type, ELEMENT_NAME, ELEMENT_ID, 
       SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS.DESCRIPTION, namespace_prefix, datatype_localname 
FROM ELEMENTS left outer join
     SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS
     on ELEMENTS.SUBSTITUTION_GROUP_ID = SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS.RID left outer join
     TAXONOMIES
     on ELEMENTS.TAXONOMY_ID = TAXONOMIES.RID left outer join
     SCHEMAS
     on ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_SCHEMA_ID = SCHEMAS.RID left outer join
     DATA_TYPES
     on ELEMENTS.DATA_TYPE_ID = DATA_TYPES.RID
```

If you are learning SQL, you should learn:

1. Proper ANSI standard JOIN syntax
2. Prefixing each field in a query with the table where it comes from
3. Using short but understandable aliases, such as "e" for elements and "t" for taxonomy.

Comment: +1 To amplify a bit, the syntax the OP used results in implicit INNER joins, where primary table rows will be excluded unless there is a matching row in all the other joined tables.  Outer join will produce the desired number of rows but some of the data retrieved from the joined tables will be null.  And yes, joins should always be written using the explicit JOIN...ON syntax in preference to the old (1980's) syntax.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for the fix and thank you Jim for the explanation!